# What is the equivalent of map.beforeRender in openlayers 4?

Tags: openlayers, openlayers-3

I have OL3 map application which use the experimental map.beforeRender event to animate auto view rotation based on GPS heading data.

Now I want to upgrade to ol 4 and I see the beforeRender function doesn't exist anymore.

```
map.beforeRender(function(map, frameState) {
if (frameState !== null) {
    // use sampling period to get a smooth transition
    var m = frameState.time - deltaMean * 1.5;
    m = Math.max(m, previousM);
    previousM = m;
    // interpolate position along positions LineString
    var c = positions.getCoordinateAtM(m, true);
    var view = frameState.viewState;
    if (c) {
        view.center = getCenterWithHeading(c, -c[2], view.resolution);
        view.rotation = -c[2];
        currentRotation = -c[2];
        rotateMap(radToDeg(view.rotation));
        marker.setPosition(c);
    }
}
return true; // Force animation to continue
});
```

so  , if today I upgrade to OL4 , what is the alternative ? where do I implement this function in order to rotate the view ?

Answer (score 1):

The [changelog for OL4](https://github.com/openlayers/openlayers/blob/master/changelog/v4.0.0.md) says you should use [view.animate()](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/ol.View.html#animate):

> The deprecated `ol.animation` functions and `map.beforeRender()` method have been removed. Use `view.animate()` instead.

So you could rotate using something like this:

```
view.animate({
  rotation: view.getRotation() - Math.PI / 2,
  easing: ol.easing.easeIn
});
```

The [animation example](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/animation.html) (*Take a tour* button) also shows how to use this in a interval function

Comment: just to be sure ... can I just copy paste my entire function into view.animte ? without doing changes ?

Comment: no, you can't. Look at the code and sample above and try to use it

Comment: I see , but you ignore the line which read the roation from gps coord : 
var c = positions.getCoordinateAtM(m, true);

So how I impelent it in this code ? ;-/

Comment: `rotation: somerotationnumber,` you can enter any rotation here and it rotates to it with an animation